# Erlang example: improper list created?

Tags: list, erlang

Erlang newbie: I'm working through the examples in Joe Armstrong's book and I'm testing his code for a "for loop." I think I'm getting an improper list, but I'm not sure why. The following (from 1st edition of book) compiles and loads just fine:

```
-module(lib_misc).
-export[for/3].

for(Max, Max, F) ->
    [F(Max)];
for(I, Max, F) ->
    [F(I)|for(I+1, Max, F)].

erl> lib_misc:for(1,10, fun(I) -> I end).
```

returns:

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

as expected.  However, if 100 is substituted for 10:

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28
29|...]

This holds true for all numbers > 29.  Is there an "automagic" (or user configurable) limit on the elements of a list?  If this code is producing an improper list, why?  Thanks in advance.

NB: I'm running the "latest" (17.3) build of erlang on Windows, Debian and NixOs and I get the same results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

everything is ok. It just a problem of presentation in the shell. If you test the length of your result `length(lib_misc:for(1,10, fun(I) -> I end))`. you will see it has the right value. You ca also print it:

```
io:format("~p~n",[lib_misc:for(1,10, fun(I) -> I end)]).
```

It is a general warning, the shell shows you the result in a "best" presentation. For long list or deep nested terms, it makes some "summary" to avoid potential hundreds of pages.

Comment: You can also use the shell `rp` command, i.e. `rp(lib_misc:for(1,10, fun(I) -> I end)).` to see the whole term, which is easier to type than `io:format`.

Comment: Useful remark @Steve, I didn't understand the meaning of the shell help for this command (`display Term using the shell's record information
`)

Comment: the shell `rp` command can print terms using record knowledge loaded into the shell with `rr` or defined there with `rd`. But `rp` also prints the entire term, not abbreviated, whether or not it contains record instances. See [the erlang shell documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html) for more information on these commands.

Comment: @Pascal and @Steve: Thank you both for your concise and informative replies.  Agree with Pascal re: shell help for rp.  I understand the need for brevity in the shell help, but perhaps this could be expanded? `(display Term using the shell's record information if available, otherwise print entire unabbreviated Term.)`